# How to reset rows in a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

below is a table that contains text boxes. I want to reset each row individually, but right now it is resetting the whole table. What is the best known method to attack this problem? At the moment I am using jquery, but I am not sure if javascript would work any better. I also did try to iterate through each row, but somehow I got the same results and nothing changed.

```css
.zui-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>


<form id="myForm">
  <table class="zui-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Born</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>reset</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="DeMarcus Cousins"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="C"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="6'11"""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="08-13-1990"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="$4,917,000"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="Isaiah Thomas"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="PG"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="5'9"""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="02-07-1989"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="$473,604"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="Ben McLemore"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="SG"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="6'5"""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="02-11-1993"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="$2,895,960"></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myForm').trigger("reset");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are really just wanting to set their value to nothing, you can always just do something like `$("tr input").val("");` where the TR would be part of your loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah that would work, but that's not really what I was looking for. Ideally would want to reset to whatever is loaded at default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your input type reset to type button.

On click such a button can set the value of each input to an empty string:

```js
// save initial values in a data attribute for each input....
$('#myForm :input:not([type="button"])').each(function(idx, ele) {
  ele.dataset.initvalue = ele.value;
});

$('#myForm [type="button"]').on('click', function(e) {
  // reset current row............
  $(this).closest('tr').find(':input:not([type="button"])').each(function(idx, ele) {
      // restore the initial value
      ele.value = ele.dataset.initvalue;
  })
});
```

```css
.zui-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <table class="zui-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Born</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>reset</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="DeMarcus Cousins"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="C"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="6'11"""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="08-13-1990"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="$4,917,000"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="Isaiah Thomas"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="PG"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="5'9"""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="02-07-1989"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="$473,604"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="Ben McLemore"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="SG"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="6'5"""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="02-11-1993"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="$2,895,960"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply this is really helpful! However, would it be possible to reset to the default values instead of setting every row's value to nothing?

Comment: Yes, you can save the init value of each input in a data attribute. on click reset you can restore the init value. Snippet updated! Let me know

Comment: @anon The concept of default values does not exist for individual rows, you will need to store those values internally using something like internal storage.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl dataset  is exactly the internal storage of an html element....

Comment: @gaetanoM It was just a suggestion.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl  Thanks for sharing. I appreciate a lot

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to use `type="reset"` for your reset buttons, just stick with `type="button"`. You do not want to reset the entire form.

1. You can add a click listener to these buttons to get the current row of the clicked button.
2. This can be achieved via: `$(e.target).parent().parent()` or `$(e.target).closest('tr')`
3. Once you have the row, you can locate your input fields and set their values to a default value or empty string.

---

### Update: Using jQuery .data()

You can store the original values as [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) for the field. This is probably the most versatile method and it allows you to store the value of any input field.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.assignDefaultValues = function() {
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
      $(this).data('defaultValue', $(this).val());
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.zui-table').assignDefaultValues();

$('.zui-table td > input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
  const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  $tr.find('td > input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).data('defaultValue') || '');
  });
});
```

```css
.zui-table {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.zui-table thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table tbody td input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <table class="zui-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Born</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="DeMarcus Cousins"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="C"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="6'11" ""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="08-13-1990"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="$4,917,000"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="Isaiah Thomas"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="PG"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="5'9" ""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="02-07-1989"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="$473,604"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="Ben McLemore"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="SG"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="6'5" ""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="02-11-1993"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="$2,895,960"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

### Storing data the old-fashioned way

Alternatively, if you want to recall the previous values, you could store the values ahead of time. This can be helpful for building an export function.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.storeTableValues = function() {
    return this.find('tbody tr').map(function() {
      return [$(this).find('td > input[type="text"]').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
      }).toArray()];
    }).toArray();
  };
})(jQuery);

const originalValues = $('.zui-table').storeTableValues();

$('.zui-table td > input[type="button"]').on('click', function(e) {
  const $button = $(e.target);
  const $tr = $button.closest('tr');
  const index = $tr.closest('table').find('tbody tr').index($tr);
  $tr.find('td > input[type="text"]').each(function(col) {
    $(this).val(originalValues[index][col] || '');
  });
});
```

```css
.zui-table {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.zui-table thead th {
  background-color: #DDEFEF;
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #336B6B;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}

.zui-table tbody td input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <table class="zui-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Born</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="DeMarcus Cousins"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="C"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="6'11" ""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="08-13-1990"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="$4,917,000"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="Isaiah Thomas"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="PG"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="5'9" ""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="02-07-1989"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="$473,604"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="Ben McLemore"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="SG"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="6'5" ""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="02-11-1993"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="$2,895,960"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Reset"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: These are some really good tips, thank you! Is it possible to reset to the default values rather than just an empty string?

Comment: your code does that it resets to the initial values @anon

Comment: @anon I updated my example to include two ways to restore the original values.

Comment: @Carlos1232 I think OP wants to restore a single row's data. I updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

> The `<input type="reset">` defines a reset button which resets all form values to its initial values.

So, you should implement a button that trigger some function that do the trick for reseting each row.

From Here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_reset.asp